# InvalidOperationException when calling second time SaveChanges in .NET Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I am uploading an Excel file to database. No problem with the first uploading. The database is being updated on the second upload but I get an error.

This is the code to upload the Excel data:

```
public void ImportData(String conString)
{
        string query = "Select [Donem],[Marka],[Tuketim] from [Sheet1$]";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);

        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        da.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();

        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [CSProjectTable]");

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            context.CSProjectTables.Add(new CSProjectTable
            {
                Donem = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Donem"]),
                Marka = dr["Marka"].ToString(),
                Tuketim = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Tuketim"])
            });
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
}
```

MyModel.Context.cs:

```
public partial class CSProjectDatabaseEntities : DbContext
{
    public CSProjectDatabaseEntities ()
        : base("name=CSProjectDatabaseEntities ")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<CSProjectTable> CSProjectTables { get; set; }
}
```

My edmx file and the SSDL section have the `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"`.

```
public partial class CSProjectTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Donem { get; set; }
    public string Marka { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Tuketim { get; set; }
}
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'DatabaseLayer.CSProjectTable' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.

Comment: The error message says there is an entity with the same primary key value. Make sure your PKs are unique

Comment: make sure your user has permission to ALTER table (required to use TRUNCATE command); also you can try run `DELETE FROM CSProjectTable`

Comment: Thank you Michael DELETE FROM CSProjectTable worked.